# VGA output suddenly not working, Why?

Tags: pi-3, raspberry-pi-os

I have been using my VGA monitor for my RPI3 Model B using a VGA to HDMI cable and it works perfectly fine, but today when i turned on my pi the monitor says "No signal" I thought that my cable is broken so that's why I bought a new one, but still no luck. There is a time when I am using my pi with a VGA monitor after using it for a while the screen goes black, i tried turning on and off, unplug and plug the cable but still no luck, but i have a solution which is to reinstall my os and after reinstalling it works perfectly fine, but today reinstalling the OS doesnt work I have tried configuring my /boot/config.txt but still no luck.

Comment: `I have tried configuring my /boot/config.txt` - can you show what you've done in that file

Comment: My adapter works perfectly without configuration from /boot/config.txt I just tried editing it after the monitor shows "No signal", right now i have freshly installed raspbian and did not touch the configuration I have tried many configuration in the /boot/config.txt from other forums but still shows no output

Comment: By the way thanks for the response, this is my first time asking question in this page.

Comment: Does connecting using VNC work?

Comment: Yes VNC is working